# ActionView::Template::Error: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to update rails from 3.2.18 to 4.0.9 and I'm receiving that error message lots of times, I have no idea what to do to fix it as you can see there is nothing non-trivial in application.html.erb, the same happens to other tag helpers like image_tag.

Thanks for the help

I leave you with a gist with the given error and all the gems we using, I can't seem to find the problem, every help is welcome.
Thank you

https://gist.github.com/Davidslv/862c57b5490d2576e19a

Comment: I once got this error when updating Rails 3 to 4, turned out to be related to Sass, you could try locking the `sass-rails` gem and locking and adding `sass` to your Gemfile to versions compatible with 4.0.x

Comment: I'm trying to lock `sass-rails` on `4.0.3` and going from `sass` 3.2.0 to 3.2.9 but nothing was successful. I can't go higher than 3.2.9 because of the 4.0.3 `sass` lock. I think my only chance is to downgrade `sass-rails`

Answer (score 1):

This got solved by separating the jasmine tests in the rake test.